# No module after bulding custom kernel -> "cannot access /lib/modules/xyz: No such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I kind of new to kernel building but I would like to try my own kernel. I pretty much followed the "how to" on this site ([elinux.org tutorial](http://elinux.org/Panda_How_to_kernel_3_5_rcx)) to install the 3.5.0-rc7 Kernel on my Pandaboard ES (running Ubuntu 12.04).

Basically I do.

Getting mainline Kernel

```
$ git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git  
$ cd linux  
$ git checkout v3.5-rcx
```

Getting special uboot and MLO for Pandaboard ES

```
$ mkdir pandaboard-es  
$ cd pandaboard-es  
$ git clone git://git.linaro.org/boot/u-boot-linaro-stable.git  
$ cd u-boot-linaro-stable  
$ git checkout -b pandaboard-es origin/Linaro-u-boot-2011.12  
$ make omap4_panda_config  
$ make
```

Make my own config file ( copied the [rc7-configfile](http://elinux.org/images/1/14/Config.3.5-rc7.1) )

```
$ vim .config  
$ sudo make menuconfig (just added OTG support)
```

build the uImage

```
$ make uImage
```

I copied the MLO u-boot.bin and the uImage to the FAT partition of my Pandaboard and then I tried to boot. The systems boots fully but throws the following message while booting:

```
*FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-rc7-dirty/modules.dep: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1  
/dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 319456/3887104 files, 10158442/31093248 blocks  
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-rc7-dirty/modules.dep: No such file or directory  
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-rc7-dirty/modules.dep: No such file or directory*
```

after the boot up I tried to load a module manually without success. This is the result:

```
*ls: cannot access /lib/modules/3.5.0-rc7-dirty: No such file or directory*
```

would be great to get your help. I dont know where the failure is..

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about your specific build architecture, but don't you have to run a 'make modules' and 'make modules_install' after 'make uImage', like after any regular kernel build?

Comment: @Altaveron: is there anything that helped you then?